# entry_points does not create custom scripts with pip or easy_install in Python?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install, setup.py

I am using simple entry points to make a custom script, with this in `setup.py`:

```
  entry_points = {
           'my_scripts': ['combine_stuff = mypackage.mymod.test:foo']
  }
```

where `mypackage/mymod/test.py` contains:

```
import argh
from argh import arg
@arg("myarg", help="Test arg.")
def foo(myarg):
    print "Got: ", myarg
```

When I install my package using this (in same directory as `setup.py`)

```
pip install --user -e .
```

The entry points do not get processed at all it seems. Why is that?

If I install with `distribute` `easy_install`, like:

```
easy_install --user -U .
```

then the entry points get processed and it creates:

```
$ cat mypackage.egg-info/entry_points.txt 
[my_scripts]
combine_stuff = mypackage.mymod.test:foo
```

but no actual script called `combine_stuff` gets placed anywhere in my `bin` dirs (like `~/.local/bin/`). It just doesn't seem to get made. What is going wrong here? How can I get it to make an executable script, and ideally work with `pip` too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was to use `console_scripts` instead of `my_scripts`. It was unclear that the scripts name was anything other than internal label for the programmer.